# Get meta value and associated user meta

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a site where users are able to publish posts with custom fields associated with them. I want to display meta values from all posts, and include which user created the post where the meta value is coming from.

So far I have been able to display all meta values from all posts. My code:

```
function get_meta_values( $key = '', $type = 'workout', $status = 'publish' ) {

global $wpdb;

if( empty( $key ) )
    return;

$r = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
    SELECT pm.meta_value FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p ON p.ID = pm.post_id
    WHERE pm.meta_key = '%s' 
    AND p.post_status = '%s' 
    AND p.post_type = '%s'
", $key, $status, $type ) );

return $r;}

$workout_leader= get_meta_values( '1_rep', 'workout' );

 foreach($workout_leader as $value){ 
  echo $value; 
 }
```

How would I go about retrieving the user meta (e.g. username) for each meta value?

Comment: you just need to JOIN the postmeta table with the usermeta table, give it a try and post your effort here.

Comment: I don't wanna come her begging for code, but I am relatively new to MySQL and database queries. Any examples that could point me in the right direction? I tried something like this, but it doesn't work at all:`<?php 
$user = $wpdb->get_results( 
 "
 SELECT post_meta.meta_key, user_meta.meta_value 
 FROM $wpdb->post_meta, $wpdb->user_meta
 WHERE post_meta.meta_key = '1_rep'
    AND user_meta.meta_value = '2'
   
 "
);

foreach ( $user as $value1 ) 
{
 echo $value1;
}
?>`

Answer (score 0):

I got some help from the wordpress stackexchange forum, that answered my question. For anyone who is interested, heres the code:

function get_meta_values( $key, $type = 'workout', $status = 'publish' ) {
    global $wpdb;

```
if ( empty( $key ) )
    return;

$r = $wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT pm.meta_value, p.post_author FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        WHERE pm.meta_key = '%s' 
        AND p.post_status = '%s' 
        AND p.post_type = '%s'",
        $key,
        $status,
        $type
    )
);

if ( $r ) {
    $user_ids = wp_list_pluck( $r, 'post_author' );
    cache_users( $user_ids );
}

return $r;
}

$workout_leader = get_meta_values( '1_rep', 'workout' );
foreach ( $workout_leader as $data ) {
echo $data->meta_value;
echo $data->post_author; // User ID

// Any other user-related data.
echo get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $data->post_author );
}
```